# EF relationships when adding to database

Tags: entity-framework

I have a question about relationships in Entity Framework when adding to database.

I have the following layers

- Web app
- Service layer
- Repository
- Data layer

Lets say i have these entities

- Course
- Department

These entities reference each other. 
In my service layer I get the course entity and the department entity. 
Then I do something like:

```
    Course.Department = department;
    Unitofwork.CourseSet.Add(Course);
    Unitofwork.SaveChanges();
```

My question is then:
Do I also need to add the department entity to the context?

Because even if I dont add the department to the DepartmentSet it is still beeing added to the database. 
Is there some kind og rule about when to add to the context and when its not necesary

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add related entities separately since EF is able to detect that automatically.

Also, even if you do add it separately, it will have no effect since the related entity is (internally) already attached to the Context and its state is already set to 'Added'.

The 'rule' you're looking for is very simple: if it's not part of the 'root' entity, you'll have to add it separately.

P.S: This is all true for Insert/Add scenario. Update/Edit scenario (from detached entity) is more complicated and changes to related entities usually aren't detected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... So theres nothing wrong with always adding them? I thinks its make the code a little bit more readable. And then i dont have problem with update/edit scenario

Comment: There's nothing 'wrong' with it *technically*, but some would argue that it's *conceptually* wrong. Since EF (being an ORM) aims to let you work in an 'Object-Orieneted' way (and abstracts away the database), adding related entities separately feels more 'Database-Oriented' to me.